# Can I set break page before end of page in HTML print?

Tags: html

Can I set break page before end of page in HTML print? I have a too long table, and I want overflowing column will appear in next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `page-break-before` (or `page-break-after` ). Just set `page-break-before: always` on those block-level elements (e.g., **heading, div , p , or table elements**) that should start on a new line.

Comment: but I dont know how long of that table, its data will be got from database.

Comment: so I don't know where I add that element for break page.